# Generate Swagger from a JSON to keep clean my .java classes

Tags: json, spring-boot, documentation, swagger, springfox

I am using Springfox v 2.7 and I'd like to generate my Swagger UI from a JSON file, to keep my Controller classes clean, and without annotations from Swawgger (@Api, @ApiDocs) either my model classes without any annotation (@ApiModelProperty, etc)....

Regards!

PD: This is a Spring boot 1.5.8 version App.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the changes you need to make:

- Only Springfox JAR needed is `springfox-swagger-ui` JAR which contains all the static UI artifacts.
- A `swagger.json` file containing all the JSON definition located under the `resources` folder.
- A custom controller having the following endpoints to meet all the requests from the `swagger-ui.html`:

  1. `/swagger-resources` endpoint which returns a JSON string representation of a `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource` object.
  2. `/swagger-resources/configuration/ui` endpoint which returns a JSON string representation of a `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration` object.
  3. `/swagger-resources/configuration/security` endpoint which returns a JSON string representation of a `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration` object.
  4. `/v2/api-docs` endpoint which returns a JSON representation of a Swagger API definition.

**You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/springfox-ui-from-json-example).**

Comment: The only thing I would change in your code is, form the JSON requests using `Map` and then use `ObjectMapper` to convert it to JSON.